# Guidelines to domesticate extraterrestrial lifeforms

Tags: domestication

Man have rules over other animals on Earth through force... correction I mean innovation and revolution of technology from knife made out of stone during our earliest confrontation with the Neanderthal (we stabbed them to extinction well done guys but why dodo birds too?) to knife consisted only of high energy photons a.k.a Laser. Our early ancestors managed to subdue wolves, wild boars, little pony and many others and developed animal husbandry. After a long periods of vigorous training negotiations between man and pets/foods finally have a breakthrough which we all take for granted till today. My question is suppose our space exploration confirmed we are not alone and in fact we are outnumbered by extraterrestrial life what are the guidelines or factors to consider if these aliens are to be domesticated?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking for? And probably reduce a bit the scope of your question, as it is the subject is [too broad](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)? Any answer would greatly depends on the types of aliens encountered. Maybe if you write a bit on which kind do we expect?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin in the future human colonies will inevitably extend its reach to the outer edge of Milky Way arms and we'll encounter many never before seen badly deformed alien creatures enroute. Suppose if we settled down on a habitable planet in another system and discovers huge diversity of non-flora and non-fauna how do we determine they are edible and stupid enough to play a game of fetch?

Comment: My point is that if someone come with some rules about dog-like aliens and another with some rules about sentient, evolved alien civilization, which are you going to pick as the best answer?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin whats the different either way we will still beat them into submission thats how our courtesy used to work but now I'm not sure any more.

Comment: Call it a "meta" problem, if you will. You asked a question, you are expected to pick an answer among the available answers (in due course). On which ground will you decide **which** will you choose?

Answer (score 1):

Dogs domesticated themselves initally. Barncats (later housecats) took the nieche on their own, following the rats which did the same.

Plants are clearly domicated by selective breeding, not combat. So are farm animals: dodo birds never were, nor were any of the ancient prey animals you refer to. So I wonder if you are using the right words, or mean something different?

An extraterrestrial life form will be domesticated in the same manner as any "alien" life form, meaning one from outside the environment it is introduced into.  If useful, it will be imported and bread using ancient methods of selecting those with desirable traits and allowing those to be "successful".  When it changes to the point that the human-selected form is not something that would be successful in the wild but exists *only* because we provide the niche explicitly for it, then it is considered "domesticated".

I don't think we use lasers for hunting in place of a knife: only for aiming sights.

You can look at how technology has affected breeding of *any* existing life forms, and I don't think we are holding anything back to apply only to extraterrestrial life.  They include understanding of inheritance, screening for detection without waiting for the trait to be expressed (and knowing for sure which recessive traits are present), purposrully causing mutations to screen for new traits, and explicit gene splicing.